# How to clean the memory occupied by a variable from the local machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am working with a .nc(netcdf) file of approx 3GB, in jupyter notebook. I read it using `xarray.open_dataset(path_to_file)` and store it in a variable called `temp`.
When I try to create a dataframe out of it using `temp.to_dataframe()` and storing it in a variable called `df_temp` it blows up the storage of my Local Drive (C).
How do I clean up the space that this variable has occupied?

- I'm using Python 3.6 and Anaconda 4.7 on Windows 10

Comment: How is your drive space involved in this?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just creating a local variable for the dataframe. Although, my Python and Anaconda directories(after installation) are in Local Drive (C) (in case if it makes any difference).

Comment: You can try to assign instead of `df_temp` to the same variable `temp`.